# Error "system is computationally singular" when trying to run panel data regression

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I'm using `plm` package to run a twoways within panel regression with a *unbalanced data set*. I already read about this error but didn't figure out how to solve this problem:

```
Error in solve.default(vcov(x)[names(coefs_wo_int), names(coefs_wo_int)],  : 
 system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.98421e-17
```

I use 5 independent variables. 3 of them are very large numbers, the other 2 are ratios. Previously, I used the log of the 3 independent variables (x2, x4 and x5)and it worked perfectly without any error messages. Is it possible that it might be due to Multicollinearity and should I actually use the logarithm data set?

```
fixednormal <- plm(ROA ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5, data=dataset4, model="within", effect="twoways")
fixef(fixednormal, effect="time")
summary(fixednormal)
```

Comment: "3 of them are very large numbers" Change their unit to make them not so large.

Comment: This does not solve the error message, but changing the unit is much easier, of course. It's funny to see that when you're in the middle of a master thesis, you think much too complex. Thanks for this obvious hint. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the unit as a workaround solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the log function to the large explanatory variables